# SQL code to find between Days only. Not dates

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to execute the code but it throws me an error. I need the days to be between 7 and 10

I have already tried running it but it is not working so far

```
select * from hive.entity.bookings_base_fact where car_number in('S424BFK',
'S275BCK',
'S257CAN',
'BANDYS',
'722YKE',
'427YNZ',
'042XUK',
'161YKD',
'029YHY',
'894VIF',
'856XHF',
'ALG16',
'364TGB',
'452YTB',
'171WSN',
'148YIC',
'599XPY',
'ZAG386',
'1LX5FU',
'1PC7PW',
'VISNOI',
'1BO1RQ',
'ZCI076',
'1LX6DH',
'ZSF986',
'1EIR205',
'1GKX072',
'RAKHRA',
'1GRK465',
'1EQO445',
'1EKU643',
'1DXD359',
'1EXA622',
'1DSJ769',
'SINGH001',
'A77027',
'1GOV986',
'1GBY431',
'1EDN031',
'1DUH537',
'1DIY218',
'WAN813',
'1DYR270',
'1ERI764',
'1DVS953',
'1GTW217',
'1GFD951',
'1ETD570',
'1GJG518',
'1GJI460',
'MIGLANI',
'1GHI708',
'1GPQ808',
'1GPT618',
'1EGF910',
'1ELU000',
'1GPP664',
'1GSF834',
'WA23600',
'1EPO234',
'1DYQ191',
'1EFG503',
'1EGK697',
'1EWY165',
'1EIX170',
'1GDP522',
'1GTP444',
'1DGF516',
'1DPC526',
'1EQM261',
'1EVC862',
'1GBX209',
'1GKZ876',
'1GNG683',
'1EEZ674',
'1GPO491',
'1EVB911',
'1GUP612',
'BV31RJ',
'CRQ71X',
'CT99PU',
'EAW37E',
'CYN07E',
'BWN62F',
'DNW45H',
'DFS57K',
'DVS85L',
'CL43PE',
'BNO46F',
'CZL21R',
'BH60VR',
'CM16EE',
'YJB08D',
'CO10RJ',
'DYW67H',
'DXL39P',
'CA10BZ',
'DWE07J',
'BV73JU',
'DPK94X',
'CJJ39S',
'CJH53E',
'CO33KZ',
'CU14BL',
'DZK23F',
'CD68JB',
'CVA62V',
'DKR25C',
'CP61CE',
'CQ55MZ',
'YCP92Y',
'DVQ94B',
'BWD26H',
'DWG35Q',
'YIV33C',
'DSN50W',
'CQ92MT',
'DXV29V',
'CHT08L',
'EAV95U',
'BN99CL',
'PTI786',
'CQ74YA',
'CK62MQ',
'CA70CH',
'CQ78UB',
'CN46RX',
'CL83WY',
'CM05DI',
'BU30HV',
'CGT93H',
'CM06TN',
'DVZ41R',
'CS35QM',
'CT03AY',
'YCP71P',
'BPI07J',
'CL43SH',
'DXV62T',
'CA99ME',
'YIU86L',
'YDE45J',
'CO96PR',
'EBN83B',
'BX19FX',
'YJK59F',
'DZB28E',
'BW50MZ',
'CK80MR',
) and year=2019 and month=06 and day between 7 and 10
```

Comment: What is your error ? Are your columns named year, month and day ?

Comment: how are the columns year, month and day formated? Since you have month as 06, I am guessing they are strings. In which case you need to include the ' '. 
Then if that still doesent work, you could do day in ('7', '8', '9', '10')

Comment: Looks like columns are string format (I'm guessing cos month value is 06), so you could convert it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to store dates in a date column with a `DATE` format, so you can use native functions and do your query like this :

```
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2019 
    AND MONTH(date) = 6 
    AND DAY(date) BETWEEN 7 AND 10
```

But in your case, I think your columns use strings, you can do this :

```
WHERE CAST(year AS INT) = 2019
        AND CAST(month AS INT) = 6
        AND CAST(day AS INT) BETWEEN 7 AND 10
```

Comment: You're welcome, consider to put an answer as good answer for other peoples.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert columns to datatype integer in the following:

```
and cast(year as int) = 2019 
and cast(month as int) = 6 
and cast(day as int) between 7 and 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of the leading zeros in the integers suggests that the columns are actually strings.  If this is the case, then the comparisons should be as strings:

```
year = '2019' and month = '06' and
day between '07' and '10'
```